# tensorflow one_hot input dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

What format are the indices in tf.one_hot? Can it be a tensor?

I have the following code:

```
prediction = tf.argmax(output, axis=1)
pred_hot = tf.one_hot(indices = predictions, depth=2)
```

If I run this

```
sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y})
# [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]  an array of either zero, one
```

Now, I want this to be a two-dim array

```
# [ [0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0] ]
```

However, running

```
sess.run(pred_hot, feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y})
```

gives an error.

So the question is what format do I input into the tf.one_hot function and why is it not working this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.one_hot()` converts `[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]` to `[ [0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0] ]`, so you don't need to feed the input you are feeding as a 2-dim array.

As a general example, suppose the input is `[1 0 2]` and the depth is 3 then `tf.one_hot()` converts it to `[ [0 1 0] [ 1 0 0] [0 0 1] ]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using depth = 2, i.e.

```
tf.one_hot(tensor, depth=2)
```